# Looking for a solution : $\int_{0}^{R}{\frac{x\cos(a+bx^2)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I try to find a solution for :

$\int_{0}^{R}{\frac{x\cos(a+bx^2)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx}$

where  $R$ is a strictly positive real and $a$ and $b$ are constant real parameters.

Inspired on this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180310/evaluating-int-0a-frac-cosux-sqrta2-x2-mathrm-dx?rq=1), I tried a variable change: $x=\sin\theta$. This leads me to a new expression (I'm not sure how to manage boundaries):

$\int^{?}_0{\cos(a+b\sin^2\theta)\sin\theta{}d\theta}$

Now I am stuck (I can't see identification with Anger or Bessel function like in [above mentionned post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180310/evaluating-int-0a-frac-cosux-sqrta2-x2-mathrm-dx?rq=1)). I have some ideas, but none of them seems to leads to a convenient solution :

- trying an integration by part on this last expression (I am still bothered by the squared sine function into cosine)?
- trying another variable change (I thought of doing the change on $x^2$, but I then lose the simplification in the square root) ?
- is there a known identification for the obtained expression (not in my knowledge)?
- should I try something else than variable change ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: a sub of $u=x^2$ and $v=u-1$ leads to an integral $$2 \int_0^R dv \, \cos{(a -b + b v^2)}$$ But that's about all I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the problem more general
$$I=\int{\frac{x\cos(a+bx^2)}{\sqrt{c^2+x^2}}dx}$$ let
$$u=\sqrt{c^2+x^2}\implies x=\sqrt{u^2-c^2}\implies dx=\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-c^2}}du$$
$$I=\int\cos \left(a-b c^2+b u^2\right) \,du$$ Now  $v =b u^2$ to make
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\int \cos \left(a-b c^2+v^2\right)\,dv$$ Now, expand the cosine
$$I=\frac {\cos(a-b c^2)}{\sqrt{b}}\int \cos(v^2)\,dv-\frac {\sin(a-b c^2)}{\sqrt{b}}\int \sin(v^2)\,dv$$ and, now, we just face [Fresnel sine and cosine  integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Back to $x$
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\Bigg[\cos \left(a-b c^2\right) C\left(\sqrt{b} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sqrt{c^2+x^2}\right)-\sin \left(a-b c^2\right) S\left(\sqrt{b} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sqrt{c^2+x^2}\right) \Bigg]$$

Comment: I think there is an error in the substitution of the second variable. Indeed, the differential term $dv$ has not been evaluated. Calculating it, we get:$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\int{}\frac{\cos(a-bc^2+v^2)}{\sqrt{v}}dv$ ... and the Fresnel integral identification is no more possible.

Comment: Okay, my problem was that there is a mistake in variable substituion. v=bu2v=bu^2 is written but v=buv=bu is applied, and it works fine !  @claudeleibovici can you correct it ? I re-upvoted the solution.